# Unable to access or browse published API in Azure portal after connecting API Management to VNet in External mode

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-gov

I am deploying Azure API Management service instance in Azure Gov Cloud.

I am connected to my VNet using External mode.

I have imported one of the On-Premise API into my API Management.

I can access developer portal and can pay around and test the API

However, I am unable to connect or browse the API from Azure Portal.

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-troubleshooting) link to troubleshoot the issue but so far no luck.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [commit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/9379441f7d95a21ee26f10ba322cc22c93d4c4c5) made on 8/29 in GitHub documentation to provide US Gov Management IP Information which was missing. Funny thing is that the Page is still showing 2/28/2019 date. So the date is not reflected correctly. However with that commit, it has solved the original problem.

Comment: But we now have another problem. Now if I try to run the API (e.g. EchoAPI) from Azure portal in the Test tab, I get 400 bad request error (unable to connect to remote server). Trying to figure that new error now. Just FYI, I am deploying the APIM in External VNET Config mode and I have not enabled any custom domain for the APIM service. Implemented all recommendation to open all ports as the azure docs for VNET integration with APIM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure required ports are open in your VNET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-common-network-configuration-issues